# Laravel 5 Multi Select not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I need help with setting this one query in laravel 5.

This is my table example... :

table name: **mytable**

```
 user_id  cost   status     created_at 
--------------------------------------
   1      10     Pending   2016-04-21 04:51:01
   1      20     Pending   2016-04-22 04:51:01
   1      100    Approved  2016-04-25 04:51:01 
   1      45     Pending   2016-04-28 04:51:01
   1      60     Approved  2016-05-01 04:51:01
   1      60     Approved  2016-05-01 04:51:01
   1      160    Approved  2016-05-03 04:51:01
   1      360     Pending   2016-05-05 04:51:01
   1      260     Approved  2016-05-12 04:51:01
   1      210     Pending   2016-05-21 04:51:01
```

basically I need One SQL statement in Laravel that will output something like this or close per user , because I might have different user ids

```
           Totalpending    Totalapproved  TotalCost

April/2016    3               1            ( add cost for April)
May/2016      1               4             ( add all cost for May)
```

I have this code so far , but how to make it all in one query ?

```
$query = DB::table('my_table')->select(DB::raw('MONTH(created_at) as m, YEAR(created_at) as y'), DB::raw('count(*) as pp'))->where('user_id' ,Auth::id())->where('status','Pending')
  ->groupBy('created_at')
  ->get();  

var_dump($query);
```

But this outputs only pending like below: ...

```
 array(1) {
  [0]=>
   object(stdClass)#321 (3) {
     ["m"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["y"]=>
      string(4) "2016"
      ["pp"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      }
   }
```

or I can have an output like this :
where "pp" > total pending , "aa" > total approved , "cc" > total cost

```
 array(1) {
  [0]=>
   object(stdClass)#321 (3) {
     ["m"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["y"]=>
      string(4) "2016"
      ["pp"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["aa"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["cc"]=>
      string(1) "175"
      }
   }
```

How to show the others approved and total cost??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were implenting this using SQL only, then something like below should help you.

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('/', MONTHNAME(`created_at`), YEAR(`created_at`)) AS `Datum`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `status` = 'Pending' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `TotalPending`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `status` = 'Approved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `TotalApproved`,
  SUM(`cost`) AS `TotalCost`
FROM `mytable`
GROUP BY `Datum`
ORDER BY `Datum` DESC;
```

But since you are using the Laravel's query builder, I guess it can be ported like the one below.

```
$query = DB::table('mytable')->select(
    DB::raw(
        'CONCAT_WS(\'/\', MONTHNAME(created_at), YEAR(created_at)) as Datum,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status = \'Pending\' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalPending,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status = \'Approved\' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalApproved,
        SUM(cost) as TotalCost'
    )
)->where('user_id', Auth::id())->groupBy('Datum')->orderBy('Datum', 'desc')->get();
```

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e1f6a/2)

Comment: Welcome, hope that you will accept the answer also :)